# How to pass options like paranoid,underscore in sequelize migration file using queryInterface

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, database-migration, sequelize-typescript

I am writing migration files using Sequelize. I wanna know how do I pass options like paranoid,underscore in QueryInterface.createTable function.